# How does async deal with closed UI?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I've learnt how to work with `async` in `C#` (`tasks` in `C++/CX`) but I'm looking for an answer from the documentation experts regarding a question that's bugging me:

> I launch a task that will later reflect in the UI *(form, page, etc...)* that launched it. But let's say the user closes it before actually completing. Or goes back/forward in a `XAML` frame/page UI.

**What is the official take on this?** I'm worried that my references will point to missing objects that might crash. From my tests... no error occurs but I'm not sure.

**PS**: *This might be a silly question but I'm a native `C++` threads' guy and one major obsession is keeping stuff within scope or copying/moving to thread context upfront.*

Comment: *missing objects that might crash* - it may crash if you do something with assumption what your UI is still on. Common approaches: 1) signal and wait (don't close UI before task is completed, signal *"I want to close"* and task should terminate itself and signal back *"ok, I am done"* and then you close UI); 2) UI-stateless task (task will check state of UI constantly before doing anything and will terminate itself gently if UI is closed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do `Task.Run(() => this.someVariable)`, that `someVariable` (and the `this` too) will keep the instance alive since the anonymous method derived from the lambda expression references to that variable, although the windows might be closed and disposed, it still exists in memory.

In the end, when the task ends, and all references are given up, the memory will be released. That is most likely the reason you receive no exceptions, while you might have a problem when accessing disposed objects.

Comment: So the UI elements are not disposed on close. They just close *visually* but objects still exist while referenced?

Comment: They are disposed, but still kept in memory. Note that disposing and garbage collecting are two totally different things.

Comment: So disposed but not actually destroyed as they are still referenced. Was worried about the `ObjectDisposedException` when I try to access them disposed ones. **Thank you!**

Comment: @CodeAngry: That is a worry indeed, so you should always check if the object you access is disposed or not.

Comment: **(facepalm)** So, before updating UI from task I'll just check if object is Disposed or not and act accordingly. Knew this had to be easy...

Comment: Indeed. It is tricky though since the object can be disposed just after you checked it since it is asynchronous :)

Comment: Well, in case I experience issues, I now know which way to go and where to look...

Answer (score 2):

One way of of making sure your task doesn't try to access disposed objects is by providing a `CancellationToken` to that task. Once your XAML is about to close, you can hook into one of its `OnClosing` methods and trigger a cancellation:

```
private CancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
```

When you create a task, pass the token along:

```
var task = Task.Run(() => 
                   {
                         cts.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                   }, cts.Token);
```

And when you're about to close, signal the token:

```
protected override void OnClosing() 
{
     cts.Cancel();
}
```

This way, you can make sure you access your UI elements only if a task was not cancelled, and avoid accessing disposed objects.

Comment: Good suggestion! In fact you have to check every time you try to access the UI if the task is cancelled, and still you can get the problem that it cancels right after you checked, but this is a good start.

Comment: @PatrickHofman - not really. If he's awaiting on the task, he can wrap it in an `OperationCancelledException`. If he's using a continuation, he can set it to `TaskCompletionOptions.NotOnCancelled`

Comment: And it's nice that I can just use one per UI and use with multiple tasks. At least that's what I've seen in examples...

Comment: @CodeAngry - Yes. You may even share the cancellation token between elements, so if any one of of them cancels the other will too. The options are endless :)

Comment: `TaskCompletionOptions`... is it `TaskContinuationOptions`? Can't find any MSDN on it.

Comment: @CodeAngry - Yes, sorry. Mixed it up